# Website unreachable using docker-compose, nginx-proxy and let's encrypt

Tags: docker-compose, lets-encrypt, hexo, jwilder-nginx-proxy

Can't manage to access my website using `docker-compose`, `nginx-proxy` and `letsencrypt`... I was following this tutorial: https://github.com/fatk/docker-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion-examples

Here is my config (of course `example.com` is not the value I'm using):

`./docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "2"

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - "/etc/nginx/conf.d"
      - "/etc/nginx/vhost.d"
      - "/usr/share/nginx/html"
      - "./volumes/proxy/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro"
    networks:
      - proxy-tier

  nginx-gen:
    image: jwilder/docker-gen
    container_name: nginx-gen
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro"
      - "./volumes/proxy/templates/nginx-compose.tmpl:/etc/docker-gen/templates/nginx.tmpl:ro"
    volumes_from:
      - nginx
    entrypoint: /usr/local/bin/docker-gen -notify-sighup nginx -watch -only-exposed -wait 5s:30s /etc/docker-gen/templates/nginx.tmpl /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

  letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    container_name: letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    volumes_from:
      - nginx
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
      - "./volumes/proxy/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw"
    environment:
      - NGINX_DOCKER_GEN_CONTAINER=nginx-gen

  blog:
    image: nginx
    container_name: blog
    volumes:
      - "./volumes/blog/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d"
      - "./volumes/blog/public/:/usr/share/nginx/html"
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=example.com
      - VIRTUAL_NETWORK=nginx-proxy
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=80
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=example.com
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=contact@example.com
    networks:
      - proxy-tier

networks:
  proxy-tier:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
```

`./volumes/blog/conf.d/blog.conf`:

```
server {
    listen                  80;
    server_name             example.com;
    root                    /usr/share/nginx/html;
}
```

My blog is under `./volumes/blog/public/`. This is a site generated by `Hexo`.

https://example.com return a loading error page.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a setup based on https://tevinjeffrey.me/how-to-setup-nginx-proxy-and-lets-encrypt-with-docker/ that I paste below. Also, make sure that you have a valid DNS record for example.com aiming at the box running the stack.

```
version: '2'

services:

  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./docker/nginx/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes_from:
      - php
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: www.example.com.ar
      LETSENCRYPT_HOST: www.example.com.ar
      LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL: info@example.com.ar

  php:
    build: ./docker/php/
    expose:
        - 9000
    volumes:
        - ./docker/data/html/:/var/www/html

  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    ports:
        - "80:80"
        - "443:443"
    volumes:
        - "/etc/nginx/vhost.d"
        - "/usr/share/nginx/html"
        - "/var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro"
        - "/etc/nginx/certs"

  letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    volumes:
        - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
    volumes_from:
        - "nginx-proxy"
```